# Launch/Deploy latest version WCF service before running unit tests in vs2012

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I want VS to deploy the latest version of the WCF every time I run my tests.

Currently I have to deploy manually, or run the WCF Service, for it to be deployed.

I'm looking for a functionality similar to starting multiple projects when debugging.

Maybe to specify the behaviour I am missing right now. I can not set breakpoints inside the webservice, as it's not run in debug-mode.

- @codespike Using standard unit testing in VS2012
- @codespike With Deploy I mean "copy latest version to local IIS, so it can be respond
  to calls over the web.
- @mayo Yes! that is a brilliant suggestion.    Bypassing the Coding and Decoding (webtransport) phase, and go straight to the classes that manipulate the data.

Comment: What do you mean by "deploy WCF?" Deploy to where? This question is very unclear.

Comment: You should also note what testing framework and test runner you are using.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but I found that WCF services are simply classes.  You can unit test them directly without attempting to host the services (testing the hosted services is more of an integration test).